# How to forward incoming requests to external URL

Tags: node.js, express, http, redirect

I'm trying to implement a load balancing system, which there is multiple storage servers, and one main server. The main server receives requests, authenticate the requester, and chooses which storage server is the best for them. If I use `res.redirect`, the client would connect directly to chosen storage server in the next repeated request, which is not good. Because in each request the main server must check if the requester is allowed to receive the resource, and the chosen storage server might change based on system conditions.
So each request must be sent to the main server. It should be something like this:

1. A client sends a request to main server
2. Main server confirms that user is allowed to receive the data.
3. Main server chooses the best storage server for the client based on system conditions.
4. Main server forwards the request to that server.
5. Client receives the data from chosen server.
6. Back to step 1.

Comment: This sounds like a convoluted solution to a problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @kevintechie I'm trying to do what a forward proxy does. Forwarding a request is different from redirecting the client. I have multiple storage servers which a main server should decide which of them is the best for the client. Then forwards the request to that server.

Comment: Then, stop doing a redirect. With a redirect, your server loses control.  The client is told to directly access another host.  Instead, have your own server fetch the request from the desired target and give the response back to the client.  That's what a proxy does.  If this is Express, there are pre-built options to do proxying with Express (search NPM).

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. What you are telling is that all traffic should pass from the main server. When this is a streaming service, the traffic would be huge. I'm looking for a way to just forward the incoming request to a specific server and the client gets the data directly form that server.

Comment: @Mikewoods - Well, that would be something like a redirect or referral.  But, you said you can't do a redirect for some unknown, unexplained reason.  So, you've somehow ruled out both possible solutions.  Please back up about 5 steps and describe your original problem from scratch IN YOUR QUESTION, including any limitations you have to work-around.  Then, maybe we can help.

Comment: If you're trying to build a proxy, then, as jfriend00 says, you'll have to proxy. What you describe is not what a forward proxy does. If by "best for the client" you mean best performance, then you probably don't want a proxy. You want a CDN. Proxies generally protect application resources behind them from direct access or to scale dynamic content. CDN's cache assets at the edge near the client.

Comment: @jfriend00 @ kevintechie Alright to be exactly clear, I edited the question. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you just have simple streaming requirements, all you need to do is give your streaming servers the same DNS name and give the URL of the asset to the client. DNS will automatically round-robin which server is sent the request. No redirects, no poxy, no CDN.

Comment: So, what's the problem with using a 302 redirect to tell the client where exactly to get the resource from?  302 is a temporary redirect.  The client is not supposed to switch to using that host persistently.  That's a temporary redirect for this one request and one resource.

Comment: @jfriend00 the problem is that in the cases the chosen server crashed or reached maximum limit or other conditions, the main server should change the destination server. With `res.redirect` the main server is out of the process. Browsers, players etc. use multiple repeated requests to get chunks of data. And all of them must be to the main server.

Comment: More and more requirements that aren't part of your original question. If you really need this level of scalability and availability, you're not going to get it at the application level. You'll need network-level tools such as CDN or sophisticated load balancers that track server performance metrics.

Comment: I agree with Kevin.  There is no application level solution that meets the requirements you are slowing exposing.  You will have to go to the network layer for that type of solution where the client thinks its talking to your main server, but some requests are actually routed to a different host, unbeknownst to the client.  In the future, please describe ALL the requirements and the entire problem from the beginning.,  That would have saved us all a lot of time and allowed us to help you more quickly.

Comment: @kevintechie I've read about load balancing solutions. In the articles they've used proxies. As far as I know a proxy is like a bridge for data. So if the main server uses a proxy for load balancing, all the traffic would be grabbed from storage servers and passed to client from the main server. I'm not sure if this is a good case for a downloading platform. I'm a programmer by the way. So I'm a little confused.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry I didn't mean to waste your time. I just had no idea how this case could be handled. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think we're beyond the correct use for Stack Overflow here. It seems like you don't really need to worry about scaling and availability regarding your app at this point. Just build your streaming app / service / content and if it takes off, then worry about scale / availability when you have a better idea of the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that a HTTP redirect is the correct solution here. Browsers could cache the redirects, which is not what you want in your case. According to the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections), a HTTP redirect should be used in one of those two cases only:

1. Temporary redirect (maintenance, downtime)
2. Permanent redirects (page moved permanently)

What you are trying to accomplish sounds like you want to proxy the requests to the underlying storage servers. Not a use case for HTTP redirects.

Since you mentioned in the comments that you do not want to proxy the request because of performance issues, but rather forward the client, have you tried the following?

You could provide an endpoint from your load balancer like this:

```
GET /api/endpoint
```

Which returns a `200 OK` response containing the correct URL for the selected content server. Your client (e.g. JavaScript) could then handle the redirect.

If you have questions, feel free to post them in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is a potential solution. The problem is that the client must handle the process then. Consider that the url to a file is http://example.com/download/file1. With this url the client must be able to get the data. But the main server chooses the storage server. And if this is a video file, the player sends repeated requests to get chunks of data. In these repeated requests, the main server might decide to change the destination server, if the previous option was off or crashed or something.

Comment: Not really an answer. It just summarizes the comments and proposes a version of the solution in the original post.